# git show --name-status letters: when can more than one letter appear?

Tags: git

Quick question about git, specifically the [--diff-filter](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) letters, as they appear when using

`git show <rev> --name-status --oneline`
.

I notice that in some of files, I get results like:

> AM    contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinUser.java

How is it possible that this file was both added and modified?
I also get results such as:

> MM    CHANGES.md

Could this caused by an ammended commit?
Are there any other possible causes?

Thanks

Comment: Those look like the output from `git status --short`, not from `git diff`.  Can you post actual cut-and-paste from a terminal session, or screen-shot from window, or whatever is applicable?  (In `git status` output, `AM` is a file that is added in the index, i.e., not in `HEAD`, and different between index and work-tree; `MM` is in `HEAD` but is modified in the index and also modified in the work-tree.)

Comment: they are actually from a git show...
I'll try to make the question clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git show` command can show merge commits as well as non-merge commits.  You're showing a merge.

When you ask `git show` to show a merge commit, it uses a "combined diff" by default.  For instance, here's (part of) a commit in the git source itself.  I used `HEAD^` here as this particular merge commit happens to have the right kind of changes to produce an interesting result.  I will give the examples first, and then explain what's going on.

```
$ git show HEAD^
commit 4109c28e055dba27d73cefb956bea5e611f66ec0
Merge: a3d54f9 e09867f
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 26 11:16:26 2014 -0700

    Merge branch 'jk/diff-tree-t-fix'
```

Let's add `--name-status --oneline`:

```
$ git show --name-status --oneline HEAD^
4109c28 Merge branch 'jk/diff-tree-t-fix'

MM      combine-diff.c
MM      t/t4038-diff-combined.sh
```

This looks much like yours, although we just have `MM` rather than `AM`.

Now let's add `-m` (this gets long so I'll snip it down):

```
$ git show -m --name-status --oneline HEAD^
4109c28 (from a3d54f9) Merge branch 'jk/diff-tree-t-fix'
M       combine-diff.c
M       t/t4038-diff-combined.sh
4109c28 (from e09867f) Merge branch 'jk/diff-tree-t-fix'
M       .gitignore
M       .mailmap
[...]
M       column.c
M       combine-diff.c
M       command-list.txt
[...]
```

The output from `-m` is the easiest to explain.  A merge commit is a commit with two or more parents, and with `-m`, the `git show` command shows a diff of the commit against each parent in sequence:

```
... - A - M
        /
... - B
```

Here merge commit `M` (`4109c28` in the case of the git sources, here) has commit `A` (`a3d54f9`) as its first parent, and `B` (`e09867f`) as its second.  Comparing the contents of `A` with `M`, we find that files `combine-diff.c` and `t/t4038-diff-combined.sh` are modified.  Comparing the contents of `B` with `M`, we find that *many* files are modified, including `combined-diff.c` (and, in output I snipped away, `t/t4038-diff-combined.sh` as well).

When git shows a "combined diff", it first filters away all files that are not changed from *both* parents (or "all parents" for a 3-or-more parent merge).  That is, it's not considered "interesting" that `column.c` was modified from `B` to `M` because it was *not* modified from `A` to `M`.  But `combined-diff.c` *was* changed in both individual diffs, so it is retained in the combined diff.

If you add `--diff-filter`, this reduces the diff even further, by retaining only those diffs that match the filter.

In any case, the combined diff's "status" part is shown as a series of status-es, one for each parent.  The sequence `AM` here means that between merge and first-parent, the file was added, while between merge and second-parent, the file was modified.  You can also get `MM` (as in the example above), `MA` (modified from first parent, added from second), `MT` and `TM`, and so on.  I'm fairly, but not completely, sure you will not see renames and copies (the documentation says that there are no score numbers and only a single path is shown, which would be a problem for rename and copy).  In each case, each letter has its usual meaning.  What you won't see here is any case with a space as one of the modified-status-letters, since that means "no change" and since "no change from some parent" is discarded from the combined diff.

For more about combined diffs, see the "COMBINED DIFF FORMAT" section of, e.g., [the `git diff-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_combined_diff_format).

Comment: An extreme example of this from the "[cthulu-merge](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2017/the-biggest-and-weirdest-commits-in-linux-kernel-git-history)" in the linux kernel: `MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM      include/sound/soc.h`.

Comment: @Zitrax Lord have mercy