# For git diff --name-status, what does the output mean?

Tags: git

when i run 
`git diff --name-status`
I am seeing lines like this:

```
MM  mm/Jenkinsfile
```

What does the 'MM' mean?

mkreiger1's 'possible duplicate' does provide useful information but like Koop4's answer it informs without citing a git document that answers this *specific* question.

Where are multiple letters (like 'M') specifically described? The 'possible duplicate' describes *why* (and thanks for that) but where is this documented?

Comment: Are you looking at a merge commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git show --name-status letters: when can more than one letter appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261351/git-show-name-status-letters-when-can-more-than-one-letter-appear)

Comment: Is your question what 'M' means (in contrast to, say, 'A'), or why there is more than one letter?

Comment: It's important here to distinguish between `git status` (which runs *two* `git diff`s) and `git diff` or `git show`, which runs *one* `git diff`, which in some special cases is a *combined* diff.

Comment: It's right there in the diff manpage, a section titled  **`DIFF FORMAT FOR MERGES`** that says what diff shows for merges. It rather unsurprisingly shows the concatenated status summary for the merged differences from each parent.

Comment: Per the phrasing of my question, I was attempting to do a simple 'git diff --name-status'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [Doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---name-status) explains, that option

> Show only names and status of changed files.

The short-format is a two-letter status code follewed by a path:

`XY PATH`

- For paths with merge conflicts, X and Y show the modification states of each side of the merge.
- For paths that do not have merge conflicts, X shows the status of the index, and Y shows the status of the work tree.
- For untracked paths, XY are ??.

Other status codes can be interpreted as follows:

```
' ' = unmodified
M = modified
A = added
D = deleted
R = renamed
C = copied
U = updated but unmerged
```

You can read more about the [short format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format) status in the related section.

Comment: OP wanted to know the meaning of the MM convention for status. I guess this is the reason for the -1 ?

Comment: Yeah ok, it tells a lot about how people think. They can't even open a link and read themselves

Comment: also, the question state:  *what does the output mean?*

Comment: Agreed on the general principle (active searching is the key) but.... your tolerance to laziness seems a bit low for this site, if I may ;-) Fine edit, anyway.

Comment: actually true, it has always been one of my weaknesses .  Critique accepted ^^

Comment: @NoBrassRing Did you check the part of the doc Koop4 [linked](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format) at the end of his answer? Granted, the first link (to diff page) was not answering to *that* part. But he edited to add the second link and extended explanation shortly after.

Comment: Yes, I failed to check the 2nd link, which provided the answer. Sorry.

Comment: Good answer but it misses out the possibility of original path.  The docs say "XY ORIG_PATH -> PATH"

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), the documentation is clearer:

See [commit 4eb56b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4eb56b56e7cb35ec1ff152f3b6e6c4533d48cbdd) (10 Jan 2021) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 644d85e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/644d85e751da29511ea2d92b6cc2ab913ecf2f3e), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4eb56b56e7cb35ec1ff152f3b6e6c4533d48cbdd): rephrase and clarify the `git status --short` format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> The table describing the porcelain format in `git-status`(1) is helpful, but it's not completely clear what the three sections mean, even to some contributors.
>
> As a result, users are unable to find how to detect common cases like merge conflicts programmatically.
>
> Let's improve this situation by rephrasing to be more explicit about what each of the sections in the table means, to tell users in plain language which cases are occurring, and to describe what "unmerged" means.

`git status` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4eb56b56e7cb35ec1ff152f3b6e6c4533d48cbdd/Documentation/git-status.txt#L187-L206):

> There are three different types of states that are shown using this format, and
> each one uses the `XY` syntax differently:
>
> - When a merge is occurring and the merge was successful, or outside of a merge
>   situation, `X` shows the status of the index and `Y` shows the status of the
>   working tree.
> - When a merge conflict has occurred and has not yet been resolved, `X` and `Y`
>   show the state introduced by each head of the merge, relative to the common
>   ancestor.
>   These paths are said to be *unmerged*.
> - When a path is untracked, `X` and `Y` are always the same, since they are
>   unknown to the index. `??` is used for untracked paths.
>   Ignored files are
>   not listed unless `--ignored` is used; if it is, ignored files are indicated
>   by `!!`.
>
> Note that the term *merge* here also includes rebases using the default
> `--merge` strategy, cherry-picks, and anything else using the merge machinery.
>
> In the following table, these three classes are shown in separate sections, and
> these characters are used for `X` and `Y` fields for the first two sections that
> show tracked paths: